# Heroku: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, curl, heroku

I have my app deployed through Heroku and have used their [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) tool to add an SSL certificate as my old, manually added certificate, had expired.  After adding my certificate and running `heroku certs` I see the following:

```
Name                Common Name(s)               Expires               Trusted  Type
──────────────────  ───────────────────────────  ────────────────────  ───────  ────
tyrannosaurs-53659  www.foobar.com               2017-10-15 12:59 UTC  True     ACM
```

but when I test my url using `curl` I see:

```
$ curl -kvI https://www.foobar.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.foobar.com/
*   Trying 54.243.71.103...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.foobar.com (54.243.71.103) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.foobar.com:-9838
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.foobar.com:-9838
```

Navigating to the link in my browser shows no error, but I'm confused why `curl` is showing an error?

Comment: I have the same issue here... did you found a way to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure how I ended up fixing it but I eventually ran into additional issues and the only fix was to migrate to a DNS provider that meets Heroku requirements found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains under "Configuring DNS for root domains".  Not sure if that'll help

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jeremy Thomas, I resolved it by contacting heroku support because I noticed that my certificate generated by ACM is missing. by running this `heroku certs:info`. the support mentioned that I've hit their internal rate limit after destroying and recreating domains, and he helped me to set shorter interval and my ACM Certificate get refreshed.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was resolved by waiting a few minutes to allow, I think, the DNS changes and SSL certs to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to ACM from manual certs sometimes certificate generated by ACM may be missed due to some reasons [rate limit or other reasons not mentioned any where :( ].

I had the same issue and it was resolved by removing and selecting ACM option.

Note:ACM will be available once status will show OK in domain section.